# Sampling random rates from poisson distribution given observed counts with Python

Tags: python, scipy, random, poisson

I want to generate rates which are consistent with observed counts according to a Poisson distribution.

It's easy to do the reverse with scipy. I can draw counts given a fixed rate

```
counts = scipy.stats.poisson.rvs(mu)
```

but I can't find an easy way with counts as the argument returning random rates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what I was actually looking for is the Gamma distribution, which has the same functional form, but is continuous.  To accomplish what I was trying to do with scipy:

```
mu = scipy.stats.gamma.rvs(counts+1)
```

The `counts+1` is just because of how the power is defined in the distribution

[Scipy Docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html#scipy.stats.gamma)

Answer (score 0):

Drawing counts from `scipy.stats.poisson.rvs(mu)` is sampling from a Poisson distribution.  If you had a set of samples (counts) from a single Poisson distribution and you want a rate, you're trying to estimate the Poisson distrbution.  To estimate the Poisson distribution compute the average counts: λ.  Then the distribution is:

P(k) = λ<sup>k</sup> e<sup>-λ</sup> / k!

The distribution can then be used to compute the probability of observing some count (k) in an interval.

If instead each of the counts is assumed to be from *separate* Poisson distribution - then you only have one sample from each and the best estimate of the distribution comes from taking the sample as the mean λ.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: Maybe drawing from a Poisson distribution isn't the right wording.  Given k counts, the probability that l is the underlying rate of the process is also P(l) = l^k e^-l / k!  So my goal is to draw possible underlying rates with frequency according to that probability.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following - if you need samples from the Poisson distribution - why can't the .rvs method be used?

Comment: I'm not trying to draw counts, I'm trying to draw lambdas for a fixed k.

Comment: Yes, but you've stated that the probability function for the rate is the Poisson distribution. So if you want samples of 'rates' according to that distribution you could call `scipy.stats.poisson.rvs(k)`